# How to add a where in validates uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I want to add a where on uniqueness validation.

This way it's wrong:

```
validates :identifier_number, uniqueness: true, if: :is_active?
```

Only validates when the record I want to validate is active.

I want to "something like this":

```
validates :identifier_number, uniqueness: proc { where is_active: true }
```

Validate every record, whether active or not, but only against "active" records. So two inactive records can have the same identifier_number, but no record can have the same indentifier_number as any record that is active.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question a bit. You only want to validate against records that are active. I know it's written there, but maybe you need to add an example to clarify.

Comment: I edited your question to be a bit more clear and added an answer, I hope I understood correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using the following:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :identifier_number, conditions: -> { where(is_active: true) }
```

API Docks for this: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following ways

```
validates :identifier_number, uniqueness: true, if: :is_active?

def is_active?
  is_active
end
```

OR

```
 validates :identifier_number, uniqueness: true,
   if: Proc.new { |a| a.is_active }
```

The rails guide explains it pretty clearly(https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Hope this helps you!

Comment: No, I want to check ALWAYS but where is_active=true. This only check when is_active?. But, thanks anyway.